# chrome box-shadow bug?

Tags: css

When I set `#wrap {height: 0; overflow: hidden}`, the inner anchor tag should be hidden, thus click on the shadow area should have nothing happened.

I tested it on Firefox and IE. Both of them works fine.

But on Chrome, when I click on the shadow area, I still get alert window.

Is it a WebKit bug?

Here is the demo:
http://jsbin.com/ofuxar/3

```
<div id="wrap">         
    <a href="#" onclick="alert('clicked')">click</a>            
</div>
#wrap {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 10px black;
}
#wrap a {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You are better off saying `display:none` rather than putting the `height: 0px`

Comment: I did not explain the problem well. Sorry for my engligh. Re-edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the height to 0 but it's attributes are still displayed.  Ergo, any styles you have applied to that element are still going to be shown.  IF you did a 1px border, it would show a 1px with that border color.  Probably the most known instance of the occurrence is when you have float elements inside of a parent div and the parent div collapses.  All margin and border elements are retained, but the div has a height of 0.

As @Andrew stated in the comment, you should use `display:none;` to hide elements.  If I may ask, what is your reasoning for setting something to `height: 0`?

**EDIT** http://jsfiddle.net/bHPFN/ As stated before, the attributes to the element cause it to NOT have a height of 0px, but instead extend the functional dimension of the element to what ever the CSS attributes delegate.